# JNI admob event listener to C++

Tags: android, admob, event-listener

I have made an Android application with C++ and I have implemented AdMob with JNI but now I have a problem: I can display ads with C++ but how can interact with eventListeners like

public void onAdClosed()

using C++?

Comment: you want to invoke java method `onAdClosed` from a native C layer?

Comment: I want to call functions on a native layer when the user closes the ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's my understanding that there's no real way to use a C++ object as a Listener in that scenario. By that, I mean that I had the same problem and never found a way to do it directly. :)

You need to have a Java class instantiated in the VM's memory, which the AdView can hold a reference to and call methods on. The most painless way to do this is to define your own subclass of AdListener that just forwards the calls back to C++ via native methods.

On a related note, did you know that AdMob has a [C++ API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/quick-start)? We just launched it at I/O this year, and it seems like it might fit your app. It's part of the larger Firebase C++ effort (you can see the [launch presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiFgxtvpE1w) on YouTube).